# Do there exist closed manifolds $M$ with $BDiff(M)$ having nontrivial first Postnikov invariant?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Given a closed compact manifold $M$, we have the first Postnikov invariant $k$ of $BDiff(M)$, namely $k \in H^3_{grp}(\pi_0 Diff(M), \pi_1 Diff(M))$.

What are known examples of manifolds $M$ where it is nontrivial? This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254468/what-is-the-first-postnikov-invariant-of-bdiffs1-times-s1).